# Cloud Foundry bosh Error 100: Can't find network

Tags: postgresql, cloud-foundry, vsphere, cf-bosh

I'm attempting to setup a service broker to add postgres to our Cloud Foundry installation. We're running our system on vmWare. I'm using this release in order to do that:

[cf-services-contrib-release](http://imagebin.ca/v/2SSXsJPZGP71)

I need to setup the networks: section in the manifest, and what I'm setting there isn't working.

This is what my networks look like in the vmWare vCenter UI:

[image: vmWare vCenter networks]

And this is what my clusters and resource pools look like in the vCenter UI:

[image: vmWare Vcenter clusters and resource pools]

I tried both with and without quotes, around the 'name' of the network. But I'm now getting an error saying that bosh can't find the network:

```
 Failed compiling packages > rootfs_lucid64/9b3f611b46e076b94b37645c98f9100e7bcef5dd: Can't find network: VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0 (00:00:01)
   Failed compiling packages > postgresql93/06163819b694f8d9836586d024f64c11efe30180: Can't find network: VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0 (00:00:01)
   Failed compiling packages > postgresql92/2867893e714aae6e6b76bd06e7aa30d47023c46e: Can't find network: VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0 (00:00:01)

Error 100: Can't find network: VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0

Task 2430 error
```

This was my latest configuration attempt:

```
networks:
- name: default
  type: manual
  subnets:
  - range: 100.114.130.0/24
    gateway: 100.114.130.1
    cloud_properties:
      name: VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0
```

I also tried using single quotes as below. But I got the same error as above!

```
networks:
- name: default
  type: manual
  subnets:
  - range: 100.114.130.0/24
    gateway: 100.114.130.1
    cloud_properties:
      name: 'VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0'
```

Our network that we're on is this one: 100.114.130.0/24

So it makes sense to select VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0 in the config.

I've tried setting all of these options in the yaml file with no quotes. And none of them seem to work!

```html
<ul>
<li>USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY: <a href="https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/18ac490e96a5e02fad65">postgres_2432_debug.txt</li>
<li>USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY_DVS: <a href="https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/4b02c7359b6415bde97f">postgres_2433_debug.txt</a></li>
<li>USH_UCS_CLOUD_FO-DVUplinks-435272: <a href="https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/e357ad872a40ac85b9ca">postgres_2434_debug.txt</a> </li>
  <li>VLAN1129_LB_100.114.129.0: <a href="https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/ebd88c27cab3cd2b6804">postgres_2435_debug.txt</a></li> 
<li>VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0: <a href="https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/b7eeb43e3d96f1a85578">postgres_2436_debug.txt</a></li> 
<li>VLAN14-ESXI_MGMT-3.156.14.0: <a href="https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/dbde624e63842721a133">postgres_2437_debug.txt</li>
 </ul>
```

I wouldn't expect VLAN1129_LB_100.114.129.0 to work, but I tried it anyway, just to be complete.

I've supplied debug dumps of each failed attempt next to each setting you see above. Surely one of them must work! But as you can see none of them did.

Here's my complete yaml file that I deployed with the 'bosh deploy' command:

```
name: cf-22b9f4d62bb6f0563b71 
director_uuid: fd713790-b1bc-401a-8ea1-b8209f1cc90c 

releases:
  - name: cf-services-contrib
    version: 6 

compilation:
  workers: 3
  network: default
  reuse_compilation_vms: true
  cloud_properties:
    ram: 5120 
    disk: 10240 
    cpu: 2

update:
  canaries: 1
  canary_watch_time: 30000-60000
  update_watch_time: 30000-60000
  max_in_flight: 4

networks:
- name: default
  type: manual 
  subnets:
  - range: 100.114.130.0/24
    gateway: 100.114.130.1
    cloud_properties:
      name: VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0 

resource_pools:
- name: 'USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY_NONPROD_01_RP' 
  network: default
  stemcell:
    name: bosh-vsphere-esxi-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent
    version: '2865.1' 
  cloud_properties:
    cpu: 2
    ram: 4096 
    disk: 10240
    datacenters:
    - name: 'Universal City' 
      clusters:
      - USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY_NONPROD_01: {resource_pool: 'USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY_NONPROD_01_RP'}

jobs:
  - name: gateways
    release: cf-services-contrib
    templates:
    - name: postgresql_gateway_ng
    instances: 1
    resource_pool: 'USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY_NONPROD_01_RP' 
    networks:
      - name: default
        default: [dns, gateway]
    properties:
      # Service credentials
      uaa_client_id: "cf"
      uaa_endpoint: http://uaa.devcloudwest.example.com
      uaa_client_auth_credentials:
        username: admin
        password: secret 


  - name: postgresql_service_node
    release: cf-services-contrib
    template: postgresql_node_ng
    instances: 1
    resource_pool: 'USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY_NONPROD_01_RP' 
    persistent_disk: 10000
    properties:
      postgresql_node:
        plan: default
    networks:
      - name: default
        default: [dns, gateway]

properties:
  networks:
    apps: default
    management: default

  cc:
    srv_api_uri: http://api.devcloudwest.example.com

  nats:
    address: 100.114.130.11 
    port: 25555 
    user: nats #CHANGE
    password: secret 
    authorization_timeout: 5

  service_plans:
    postgresql:
      default:
        description: "Developer, 250MB storage, 10 connections"
        free: true
        job_management:
          high_water: 230
          low_water: 20
        configuration:
          capacity: 125
          max_clients: 10
          quota_files: 4
          quota_data_size: 240
          enable_journaling: true
          backup:
            enable: false
          lifecycle:
            enable: false
            serialization: enable
            snapshot:
              quota: 1

  postgresql_gateway:
    token: f75df200-4daf-45b5-b92a-cb7fa1a25660
    default_plan: default
    supported_versions: ["9.3"]
    version_aliases:
      current: "9.3"
    cc_api_version: v2
  postgresql_node:
    supported_versions: ["9.3"]
    default_version: "9.3"
    max_tmp: 900
    password: secret
```

How can we get past this issue?

Comment: Can you try, in your `default` network `cloud_properties`, to change the name from `VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0` to `USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY/VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0`.  The folder nesting is important.

Comment: Hi Amit!  thanks for your reply to my question.
​Your suggestion to nest list the nested folders from wmare in the yaml file seems to be working!
name: USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY/VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0
is what appears to have done the trick
however the bosh deploy has been running for a really long time now!  It's been running for almost 4 hours at this point and hasn't completed yet.
Is this to be expected? or do you think there is something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From  [Amit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623318/cloud-foundry-bosh-error-100-cant-find-network#comment56993966_34623318):

The name used in Cloud Properties must include any nested sub-folders.  In the provided configuration the network is nested under USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY, so the value for `name` should reflect that, i.e. `USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY/VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0` no quotes are required.

```
networks:
- name: default
  type: manual
  subnets:
  - range: 100.114.130.0/24
    gateway: 100.114.130.1
    cloud_properties:
      name: USH_UCS_CLOUD_FOUNDRY/VLAN1130_LB_100.114.130.0
```